# My computer won't stay open even after changing the power option

Tags: windows-7, sleep

I changed "Dim the display", "Turn off the display", and "Put the computer to sleep" all to NEVER. But after around 10 minutes, the computer screen still dimmed and it went to sleep. I'm downloading something so I need my computer to stay powered up. Can anyone help?

My computer is Window 7.

Answer (score 0):

I do not use Window so I can't assist you with the settings issue. 
One good solution to downloading the items is to use a download manager.
However, I am not even sure if your computer needs to be awake to conduct a normal download.

Comment: A sleeping computer cannot download anything because it is asleep.

Comment: Depends on the way the computer sleeps. Some computers only nap.

Comment: Do you have a source for this?

Comment: The fact that in the documentation for Windows they talk about napping.

Comment: In Windows 8, Microsoft introduces Connected Standby - a new power state that enables compatible PCs to be always reachable and up-to-date. **Not supported in Windows 7**. It wakes up the pc when something interesting happens. So it is no longer sleeping.

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice the version.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Advanced settings. Look at "sleep" and "display".

Comment: Where is the advanced setting?

Comment: In the power component of the Control panel. You must have gone there to set what you did, I think.

Comment: oh that. yes, i've changed it too, but it still doesn't work